# Semaphore.WaitOne() never returns true, despire avaiablilities

Tags: c#, multithreading, unity-game-engine, semaphore

I'm working with a semaphore and threading to try to manage chunk loading for a voxel game I'm working on. My general set up, is I have a queue manager job that creates a semaphore and child jobs that wait on it. I've followed all the examples I can, but I cannot figure out why when I am calling WaitOne() on my semaphore in my child jobs, the code never continues for any thread except the main one.

CODE:
Here is the constructor for the Queue manager job:

```
  /// <summary>
  /// Create a new job, linked to the level
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="level"></param>
  protected QueueManagerJob(int maxChildJobsCount = 10) {
    queue = new List<QueueObjectType>();
    runningChildJobs = new Dictionary<QueueObjectType, IThreadedJob>();
    childJobResourcePool = new Semaphore(maxChildJobsCount, maxChildJobsCount);
  }
```

This is the function that the queue manager job runs on it's queue:

```
  /// <summary>
  /// The threaded function to run
  /// </summary>
  protected override void jobFunction() {
    // This job will continue until all queue'd chunks are loaded
    while (queue.Count > 0) {
      queue.RemoveAll((queueObject) => {
        // if the chunk is already being loaded by a job
        if (runningChildJobs.ContainsKey(queueObject)) {
          IThreadedJob chunkLoaderJob = runningChildJobs[queueObject];

          // if it's done, remove it from the running jobs and remove it from the queue
          if (chunkLoaderJob.isDone) {
            runningChildJobs.Remove(queueObject);
            return true;
          }

          // if it's not done yet, don't remove it
          return false;
          // if it's not being loaded yet by a job, and we have an open spot for a new job, start and add it
        } else {
          IThreadedJob chunkLoaderJob = getChildJob(queueObject);
          runningChildJobs[queueObject] = chunkLoaderJob;
          runningChildJobs[queueObject].start();

          // don't remove the running job from the queue yet
          return false;
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

This is the majority of the child job:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Threaded function, serializes this chunks block data and removes it from the level
    /// </summary>
    protected override void jobFunction() {
      // wait until we have a resouces, or the job is canceled.
      if (parentResourcePool.WaitOne(-1, isCanceled)) {
        doWork();

        parentResourcePool.Release();
        // if the job is canceled, abort after releasing the resource
      } else {
        abort();
      }
    }
  }
```

and that's where it stops running. Each thread stops at

```
if (parentResourcePool.WaitOne(-1, isCanceled)) {
```

an doesn't seem to continue any further.
They all end up looking like this in the debugger:

[image]
[image]

Also here is a link to my base ThreadedJob class that both of these classes extend:
https://github.com/SuperMeip/MarchingCubesCSharp.A1/blob/master/Assets/Scripts/Jobs/ThreadedJob.cs

just in case the issue may be related to that.

Comment: Please don't post your code as image.

Comment: updated to code

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you fully understand the producer consumer pattern. This might help you: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/producer-consumer-problem-using-semaphores-set-1
The worker threads that are waiting on the semaphore will continue once the semaphore is signaled (someone has to call parentResourcePool.Release() when a new item is added to the queue).

Comment: But I'm starting the semaphore with the same open threads as I'm creating it with. 
Hence: `childJobResourcePool = new Semaphore(maxChildJobsCount, maxChildJobsCount);` as opposed to `childJobResourcePool = new Semaphore(0, maxChildJobsCount);`

Comment: That's true, but the pattern is still weird, for example if doWork throws an exception (I don't know how's that's handled by the jobFunction called) the semaphore won't be incremented back so a thread will block indefinetly next time you wait.

Comment: Neat, but why are none running at all? If what I said is true, 10 threads should run at the very least, none do.

Comment: Are you sure you're not passing the same semaphore to multiple objects? I see ChildQueueJob's ctor takes a semaphore as an argument.

Comment: I am passing it to multiple objects, this is the type of pattern I was following:
https://www.infoworld.com/article/3088099/my-two-cents-on-mutex-and-semaphore-in-c.html

Comment: I can't figure out what's wrong with your code, but I don't understand what are you trying to synchronize - You create N (possibly > 10) threads, then you allow only 10 to perform work at a given time. Why not just create 10 threads and perform work on them using the producer-consumer pattern.

Comment: Because I'm not using that pattern. I don't see how I could in a loop without freezing the loop.

Comment: Can we view the implementation of `queue.RemoveAll()` ?

Comment: Oh, I see it is a standard List, thought you had a custom Queue (the RemoveAll method is not a part of the standard Queue class)

Comment: Yea sorry! I'm using a list haha